# Cloudfront with S3 origin returns AccessDenied when using OAI restricted bucket policy

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to deploy a static website to S3, and serve it up via Cloudfront. I am using serverless to generate the Cloudformation resources. Once the resources are created, my build process (in CodeBuild and CodePipeline), runs the npm install, npm run build and transfers the build dir to s3 to serve the content. For context, I am using react, specifically create-react-app.
After deploying, all resources are created as expected, but the Cloudfront endpoint returns the following "Access Denied" exception, which I am familiar with in S3:

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId><requestId></RequestId>
  <HostId><hostId> 
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

This makes me believe its the S3 bucket policy, which I have set to be have a Principal value of the `Origin Access Identity` attached to the CDN. So I'm a little unsure what is missing here to get this working. Any help is appreciated. Below is my info.

---

**Update: The index.html is accessible but the static files are not. I've added the bucket policy below, and here is the file structure of the bucket:**

---

```
asset-manifest.json
manifest.json
index.html
static/
```

Cloudformation template generated from serverless deployment:

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
    "Website": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "WebsiteConfiguration": {
          "ErrorDocument": "index.html",
          "IndexDocument": "index.html"
        }
      }
    },
    "CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
      "Properties": {
        "CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig": {
          "Comment": "Access Identity for cdn"
        }
      }
    },
    "ReadPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Bucket": {
          "Ref": "Website"
        },
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "s3:GetObject",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                    {
                      "Ref": "Website"
                    },
                    "/*"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "Principal": {
                "CanonicalUser": {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
                    "S3CanonicalUserId"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "Distribution": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
      "Properties": {
        "DistributionConfig": {
          "Origins": [
            {
              "DomainName": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "Website",
                  "DomainName"
                ]
              },
              "Id": {
                "Ref": "Website"
              },
              "S3OriginConfig": {
                "OriginAccessIdentity": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/",
                      {
                        "Ref": "CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity"
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "Enabled": true,
          "HttpVersion": "http2",
          "DefaultRootObject": "index.html",
          "CustomErrorResponses": [
            {
              "ErrorCode": 404,
              "ResponseCode": 200,
              "ResponsePagePath": "/index.html"
            }
          ],
          "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
            "AllowedMethods": [
              "DELETE",
              "GET",
              "HEAD",
              "OPTIONS",
              "PATCH",
              "POST",
              "PUT"
            ],
            "DefaultTTL": 3600,
            "ForwardedValues": {
              "QueryString": true,
              "Cookies": {
                "Forward": "none"
              }
            },
            "TargetOriginId": {
              "Ref": "Website"
            },
            "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https"
          },
          "ViewerCertificate": {
            "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ServerlessDeploymentBucketName": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "ServerlessDeploymentBucket"
      }
    },
    "WebsiteUrl": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "Website",
          "WebsiteURL"
        ]
      }
    },
    "WebSiteBucket": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "Website"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

S3 bucket policy generated:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity {ID for the OAI}"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKETNAME}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATED**

S3 Bucket YAML file:

```yaml
Resources:
  Website:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        ErrorDocument: index.html
        IndexDocument: index.html
Outputs:
  WebsiteUrl:
    Value: !GetAtt Website.WebsiteURL
  WebSiteBucket:
    Value: !Ref Website
```

Cloudfront YAML file:

```yaml
Resources:
  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: Access Identity for cdn
  ReadPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref Website
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: 's3:GetObject'
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: 
            !Join [ '', [ 'arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref Website, '/*' ] ]
          Principal:
            CanonicalUser: !GetAtt CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId
  Distribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          -
            # Use the Website as the origin
            DomainName: !GetAtt 'Website.DomainName'
            Id: !Ref Website
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Join [ '', [ 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity] ]
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        # Since React takes care of our routing, we need to make sure every path is served via index.html
        # Configure the CDN cache
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - DELETE
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
            - PATCH
            - POST
            - PUT
          DefaultTTL: 3600
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: true
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          # The origin id defined above
          TargetOriginId: !Ref Website
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https" # we want to force https
        # The certificate to use when using https
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
```

Bucket Policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity {Id}"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket-name}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Marcins answer above, that confirmed that everything was fine with the permissions for the index.html but the 403 persisted. After some lengthy investigation, I found [this](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/fixing-403-access-denied-errors-when-hosting-react-router-app-in-aws-s3-and-cloudfront) post here, which details the need to add a specific error response for 403 to the Cloudfront Distribution, similar to the one shown for 404. So my new CustomErrorResponse lokks like this:

```
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
          - ErrorCode: 403
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer based on comments.

I tried to **replicate** the issue and deployed your YAML templates in my sandbox account. I found that they are **correct**. The sample `index.html` that I uploaded to the bucket created works as expected and is accessible from CF distro created using url of the form:

```
https://d1237123arhp6.cloudfront.net/
```

No issues with CF distro, bucket policy nor OAI were identified. The **template works** as is without modifications.

Template used:

```
Resources:

  Website:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        ErrorDocument: index.html
        IndexDocument: index.html
        
  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: Access Identity for cdn

  ReadPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref Website
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: 's3:GetObject'
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: 
            !Join [ '', [ 'arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref Website, '/*' ] ]
          Principal:
            CanonicalUser: !GetAtt CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId

  Distribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          -
            # Use the Website as the origin
            DomainName: !GetAtt 'Website.DomainName'
            Id: !Ref Website
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Join [ '', [ 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity] ]
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        # Since React takes care of our routing, we need to make sure every path is served via index.html
        # Configure the CDN cache
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - DELETE
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
            - PATCH
            - POST
            - PUT
          DefaultTTL: 3600
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: true
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          # The origin id defined above
          TargetOriginId: !Ref Website
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https" # we want to force https
        # The certificate to use when using https
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
```

Comment: Could you provide an update as to what this change would look like in my example? I have tried several approaches and none are working. I have also taken a look at this example, which follows my approach https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-secure-static-site/blob/master/templates/cloudfront-site.yaml

Comment: @johnny_mac I tried, but your template is invalid json. Its missing lots of parts, thus I can't just copy and paste it to try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I included the generated template from the serverless deployment, thinking that would be more helpful. I have now added the original cfn YAML files for the bucket and distribution. Hopefully that helps, and thanks for letting me know

Comment: @johnny_mac I deployed your template in my sandbox acc. It all works. Bucket, CF distro, and the sample `index.html` that I use work fine. Are you sure that you are using domain of the form `https://d3e0234kuarhp6.cloudfront.net/` to access your websbite? Regular S3 bucket endpoint will not work. Btw, I have to update answer that it all works in my evaluation.

Comment: Now I'm confused. So you did not change anything and it worked for you? I am using the correct domain format

Comment: @johnny_mac I just put bucket and cf distro to same template, but haven't modified any resources. I added it to answer, you can just copy and paste it and deploy. Then you just have to copy your static webstie files to the bucket created.

Comment: I noticed that my index.html is accessible but the static prefix is not. I updated the question to include the file structure and the bucket policy. I thought the permission of bucket/* would grant access to all objects, but it seems I'm wrong. I have not found any other option in my research yet, any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong in that scope?

Answer (score 1):

Update the S3 bucket policy will fix this issue. Along with s3:GetObject use listbucket permission as well then it works as expected. I'm posting bucket policy in json format you can change it to yaml format

```
{
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity FOO"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity FOO"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```